# How to work with integer limits in C++. The number "-91283472332" is out of the range of a 32-bit signed integer

Tags: c++, function, limit

**Some problems in code. I must convert a string to an integer. But have limited, 32-bit signed integer. I used the `stoi() function, and did not remember about spaces in string, however using big numbers are impossible. **
My code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;

int myAtoi(string str)
{
    int Res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        if (str[0] >= 'a' && str[0] <= 'z')
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ')
            i++;
        // if(str[i]>='0' || str[i]<='9' )
        //// if(str[i]==' ')
        ////    i++;
        Res = stoi(str);
        cout << "Res:" << Res << endl;
        if (Res <= INT_MIN)
        {
            return INT_MIN;
        }
        if (Res >= INT_MAX)
        {
            return INT_MAX;
        }
    }
    cout << "MIN=" << INT_MAX << endl;
    cout << "Res=" << Res;
    // return Res;
}
```

Comment: That what [`std::stoll`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) exists for :)

Comment: `if(str[0]>='a' && str[0]<='z')` -- Believe it or not, this is not the way you should check for lower case character.  Use [std::islower](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/islower)

Comment: *Please* indent your code.  It's just an unreadable mess.

Comment: If you're going to use [stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), then you should have prepared to `catch` the exception that can be thrown.  So are you going to try and code every single case where an exception will be thrown to avoid having an exception thrown?  That seems like what you're trying to do.  If so, it will be a fruitless exercise.

Comment: If you don't care about the value of the number if it's outside the range, you can use a [`try-catch` block](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch) to catch the [out_of_range exception](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/out_of_range/)

Comment: Honestly, I don't see the point of the `myAtoi` function if it's going to call `std::stoi` (or `std::stoll`).  Either the string is good, and `stoi` will not throw an exception, or it is not good and an exception will be thrown.  A true, user-defined `myAtoi` function would have no calls to `stoi`, and instead parse the entire string without any conversion help.  That means you have to be responsible for everything -- checking *and* conversion.

Comment: What is the point of looping through `str` looking for spaces if you are just going to call `stoi()` on the entire `str` anyway?  Why call `stoi()` X times, where X is the `str`'s size? That makes no sense. Also, `stoi()` will not return values that are outside of the range of an `int`, so the `INT_MIN`/`INT_MAX` checks are useless. `stoi()` throws exceptions on failure.  If you want to manually check ranges without exceptions, use `strtol()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the help of `stoll()` which converts a `std::string` object into `long long` type integer:

```
void printLongNumber(std::string str) {
    auto number = stoll(str);
    std::cout << number << std::endl;
}
```